# How to add foreign key to child table, when there is no matching data with PK parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

For a study related assignment i need to do some SQL query's. 
When i wanted to start i noticed that a child table has no FK id field, and i figured that it is impossible for that table to have a FK_constraint.

I can start over and rerun the script i got with the assignment that would probably fix this problem, but from curiosity i would like to know how to solve a problem like this, i have searched on google and stackoverflow but did not find anything close enough.

As far as i know, i need the FKid in the child-table to be able to Join the parent and child table.

My parent table haves data about clubmembers. 
( fname, lname, sex, email etc,..)

The child table holds address details for each club member.
( streetname, zip code, residence, )

I want to join the child-table on the parent-table using the userID in the parent-table.

**like this:**

```
select * from clubmember c
join adress a on a.userid = c.userid;
```

Since the address table did not have a userid column, i have added it to the table, and i thought if i copy all the userid's from clubmember to the address table i could make a fk and join them.

But when i try to copy the userid's from clubmember and "paste" the data into the address table, new rows are been made, only containing the ID's. I want to insert those userid's into the excisting rows containing the address details, so i can link them back to the clubmembers.

**I used this query to copy the data:**

```
insert into adress (userid) 
select clubmember.userid from userid;
```

Is it possible what i am trying to do? and is it a good way to fix the lost FK from the address table? (without using a backup)

Feedback is welcome as it will accelerate my understanding with SQL or stack overflow.

Comment: The INSERT statement will create new rows.  You need to use an UPDATE statement to edit existing rows.  In this case, it might be easier to manually go into the address table and type in a userid if all you're doing is creating sample data, and you don't have a lot of existing rows.

Comment: Basically, you're stuck. If the fk assignment wasn't there then you have no way of knowing which address belongs to which user

Comment: @PhillipXT Thanks i will try UPDATE instead of INSERT!

Comment: @Strawberry So when this happends in a real database, you would have a big problem , cause it is not possible to sort this out? , for now ill just give all the clubmembers a address, its not important that the data needs be correct for now.

Comment: Correct.  If the addresses had to match the club members in a real database, there'd be no way to do it.  My suggestion was just for creating sample data for testing where it doesn't matter if they match up.

Comment: Yes. But only an idiot would design such a database.

Comment: @PhillipXT `update adress a
set a.userid = (select clubmember.userid from clubmember) 
where a.userid is null  ;` Does not work because the subquery returns more then 1 row. I want to copy all rows from clubmember.userid to address.userid.

Comment: @Strawberry That would be my teacher haha, i know fixing up a db like this is bad, but i would like to know out of interest what is possible and not ;)

Comment: @Do'Zorak Not really, that's why I suggested doing it manually.  You wouldn't be able to get all the club members linked up that way because it will upate all addresses with a single userid.